# Replace nulls by default values in oracle

Tags: plsql

Please concern following oracle beginner's case:

Table "X" contains customer data:

```
ID  Variable_A  Variable_B  Variable_C  Variable_D
--------------------------------------------------
1   100         null        abc         2003/07/09
2   null        2           null        null
```

Table "Dictionary" contains what we can regard as default values for customer data:

```
Variable_name  Default_Value
----------------------------
Variable_A     50
Variable_B     0
Variable_C     text
Variable_D     sysdate
```

The goal is to examine the row in "X" by given ID and replace null values by the default values from "Dictionary". The concrete question is about the optimal solution because, for now my own solution lies in use of looping with MERGE INTO statement which is, I think, not optimal. Also it is necessary to use flexible code without being ought to change it when new column is added into "X".

Comment: I assume you are talking about a dynamic replacement in a SELECT and don't want to update your table "X"?

Comment: @Marvin All null values in "X" for given ID should be updated by those values that reside in "Dictionary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know which fields of table X will be null, you should provide every row with every default value. And since each field of X may be a different data type, the Dictionary table should have each default value in a field of the appropriate type. Such a layout is shown in this<kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/020124/1)</kbd>.

A query which shows each row of X fully populated with either the value in X or its default becomes relatively simple.

```
select  ID,
        nvl( Var_A, da.Int_Val ) Var_A,
        nvl( Var_B, db.Int_Val ) Var_B,
        nvl( Var_C, dc.Txt_Val ) Var_C,
        nvl( Var_D, dd.Date_Val ) Var_D
from    X
join    Dict  da
    on  da.Name = 'VA'
join    Dict  db
    on  db.Name = 'VB'
join    Dict  dc
    on  dc.Name = 'VC'
join    Dict  dd
    on  dd.Name = 'VD';
```

Turning this into an Update statement is a little more complicated but is simple enough once you've used it a few times:

```
update  X
    set (Var_A, Var_B, Var_C, Var_D) =(
        select nvl( Var_A, da.Int_Val ),
               nvl( Var_B, db.Int_Val ),
               nvl( Var_C, dc.Txt_Val ),
               nvl( Var_D, dd.Date_Val )
        from    X InnerX
        join    Dict  da
            on  da.Name = 'VA'
        join    Dict  db
            on  db.Name = 'VB'
        join    Dict  dc
            on  dc.Name = 'VC'
        join    Dict  dd 
            on  dd.Name = 'VD'
        where   InnerX.ID = X.ID )
where   exists(
        select  1
        from    X
        where   Var_A is null
            or  Var_B is null
            or  Var_C is null
            or  Var_D is null );
```

There is a problem with this. The default for Date types is given as `sysdate` which means that it will show the date and time the default table was populated not the date and time the Update was performed. This, I assume, is not what you want. You could try to make this all work using dynamic sql, but that will be a lot more complicated. Much too complicated for what you want to do here.

I see only two realistic options: either store a meaningful date as the default (9999-12-31, for example) or just know that every default for a date type will be `sysdate` and use that in your updates. That would be accomplished in the above Update just by changing one line:

```
               nvl( Var_D, sysdate )
```

and getting rid of the last join.

Answer (score 2):

The direct way is to use

```
update X set
  variable_a = coalesce(variable_a, (select default_value from Dictionary where name = 'Variable_A')),
  variable_b = coalesce(variable_b, (select default_value from Dictionary where name = 'Variable_B')),
  ... and so on ...
```

Generally it should be fast enough.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. However sometimes we need to expand out data vector which means that each time we must change the code by adding more columns into it. Preferable to have flexible solution.